# Can a werewolf turn a muggle into another werewolf?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf

We [have established](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10048/is-lycanthropy-a-magical-virus) that, in all likelyhood, in HP universe, Lycanthropy is a contagion that has magical properties, and is not merely a virus (despite being a metaphor for one as intended by JKR).

As such, is there any canon evidence for what would happen should an HP werewolf bite and try to infect a Muggle? More specifically, would said Muggle have a chance of turning into a werewolf?

Comment: Isn't Greyback a werewolf who isn't a wizard? I.e. a muggle werewolf?

Comment: @NominSim - Beats me.

Comment: I thought it was implied...but I can't remember...

Comment: @NominSim Greyback has a wand. Bellatrix takes it from him when questioning him about where he found the Sword of Gryffindor. *“Where did you get this sword?’ she whispered to Greyback as she pulled his wand out of his unresisting grip.” - Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23, (Malfoy Manor)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, a Muggle can be turned into a Werewolf:

> Werewolves spend most of their time as humans (whether
>   wizard or Muggle). Once a month, however, they transform into
>   savage, four-legged beasts of murderous intent and no human
>   conscience.
>   and
>   Once a month, at the full moon, the
>   otherwise sane and normal wizard or Muggle afflicted transforms
>   into a murderous beast.
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* - Newt Scamander - Scholastic - pages X and 42</sub>

It doesn't indicate anywhere that the symptoms of Lycanthropy differ between wizard or Muggle. A werewolf is a werewolf, its origins aside.

Comment: This raise the question of how does/can a muggle Werewolf (or even those around them) comprehend the monthly change without learning about the magical world?

Answer (score 3):

From [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves):

> In the late nineteenth century the great English authority on werewolves, Professor Marlowe Forfang, undertook the first comprehensive study of their habits. He found that nearly all those he managed to study and question had been wizards before being bitten. He also learned from the werewolves that Muggles ‘taste’ different to wizards and that they are much more likely to die of their wounds, whereas witches and wizards survive to become werewolves.

That doesn't necessarily rule out *any* existence of muggle werewolves, but they are by and large, wizards.

Comment: Your quote definitely proves the existence of Muggle werewolves. If "nearly all those" werewolves he studied were wizards, then they weren't *all* wizards, and therefore some of them had to be Muggles.